# IE9 Uploadify Issue: text blocks upload button from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, uploadify

QA found a bug with an Uploadify upload button that only exists in IE9. Chrome, Firefox, etc. work appropriately.

Issue:
Nothing happens when you click on the "Upload" text part of the upload button. But when you click on the button outside the "Upload" text it works as it should. I can't figure out what the issue is.

|___________| Upload |___________|

........   ^= Clicking here works =^

Here's my attempt to reproduce the code:

html

body

... (pretty deep) ...

(`div class="uploadify-button" id="uploadWrapper-button" style="height: 15px; line-height: 15x;"`)

(`span class="uploadify-button-text"`) => Text - Upload

(`object width="100%" height="15" class="swfupload uploadifybuttonallign" id="SWFUpload_0" data="/uploadify/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1437..."/`)

... (backing out) ...

body

html

Comment: Have you tried setting the `z-index` of the clickable element to a higher value? It's hard to tell without seeing the full code, but that may prevent clicks from reaching the text `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is one you probally wont like. Dont worry about IE9. It will be obsolite soon anyways when windows 10 is released. Microsoft has already stated that they are already pushing hard for all IE's to be current.